# update a record in mongodb through mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to update existing record in a collection of `mongodb`. existing record is `{UserName: "niren",AccessToken:"abced",RefreshToken:"fghigh"}` and I want to update as `{UserName: "niren",AccessToken:"mobile",RefreshToken:"phone"}`. I used following code but it's not working.

```
myModel.update({UserName:"niren"},{$inc:{AccessToken:"mobile",RefreshToken:"phone"}},function(err){
        if(err){
                    console.log("some error happened when update");
                }
                else{
                    console.log("update successfull! with name = " + "niren");
                    myModel.findOne({UserName:"niren"}, function(err, users) { 
                        console.log("updated : " + users);
                    });
                }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake, I shouldn't use `$inc`. I should have used `{AccessToken:"mobile",RefreshToken:"phone"}` instead of `{$inc:{AccessToken:"mobile",RefreshToken:"phone"}}`. Now its working fine.